# How to check an object for a value

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hey I created my first app in react native and i run into some trouble, i simple would like to know how i can check an object for an specific value from a local storage. This is what i have so far, i know its not that much.

```
handleClick = (item)=>{
store.get('myobject').then((res) =>
console.log(res)
)
```

this is my res object:

```
[
{ id: '456', p: 'hey' },
{ id: '464', p: 'ho' },
{ id: '467', p: 'lets' },
{ id: '263', p: 'go' }
]
```

and as example i would like to know, if id 467 is in the object.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the `some` method of Array:

```js
var res = [
    { id: '456', p: 'hey' },
    { id: '464', p: 'ho' },
    { id: '467', p: 'lets' },
    { id: '263', p: 'go' }
];

var found = res.some(item => item.id === '467');

console.log(found);
```

Essentially, as it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at-least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a forEach loop and check for your desired value:

```js
var res = [
{ id: '456', p: 'hey' },
{ id: '464', p: 'ho' },
{ id: '467', p: 'lets' },
{ id: '263', p: 'go' }
]

function containsCheck(array) {

  var found = false;
  
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.id === '467') {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  
 return found;
  
};

console.log(containsCheck(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can check [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) This lib is a nice thing to have in a project when working with collections or objects.